# svg rendering issue on firefox

Tags: svg, firefox, rendering, subpixel

I have an incomplete SVG rendered on Firefox and I don't know why, I tried it on many other browsers like Chrome, safari and edge and it's working fine, the view on Firefox as the following:

[image]

and this is the svg file:

```html
<svg width="435.904"
    height="174.935"
    viewBox="235.034 260.626 326.928 131.201"
    class="displayed_equation"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M -0.0019375 0.00090625 L 6.658219 0.00090625"
            transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 429.041 274.747)"
            fill="none"
            stroke-width=".914"
            stroke="#000"
            stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
    <path d="M 0.00171875 0.00090625 L 6.657969 0.00090625"
            transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 516.885 274.747)"
            fill="none"
            stroke-width=".914"
            stroke="#000"
            stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
    <path d="M 0.001875 0.00028125 L 6.658125 0.00028125"
            transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 427.92 313.012)"
            fill="none"
            stroke-width=".914"
            stroke="#000"
            stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
    <path d="M 0.000625 0.00028125 L 6.656875 0.00028125"
            transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 515.765 313.012)"
            fill="none"
            stroke-width=".914"
            stroke="#000"
            stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
    <path d="M 0 -0.001875 L 6.65625 -0.001875"
            transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 447.25 346.295)"
            fill="none"
            stroke-width=".914"
            stroke="#000"
            stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
    <path d="M 0.0015 -0.001875 L 6.65775 -0.001875"
            transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 512.436 346.295)"
            fill="none"
            stroke-width=".914"
            stroke="#000"
            stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
    <path d="M -0.00175 -0.000125 L 6.658406 -0.000125"
            transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 442.408 379.578)"
            fill="none"
            stroke-width=".914"
            stroke="#000"
            stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
    <path d="M 0.0015 -0.000125 L 6.65775 -0.000125"
            transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 512.436 379.578)"
            fill="none"
            stroke-width=".914"
            stroke="#000"
            stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
    <g font-family="NagwaMath"
        font-size="13.5">
        <text y="278.217"
                x="233.768">|</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="237.359">8</text>
        <text y="278.405"
                x="246.258">(</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="251.046">0</text>
        <text y="278.405"
                x="257.704">)</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="265.48">−</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="278.149">1</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="284.807">2</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="291.465">|</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="299.037">=</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="312.701">1</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="319.359">2</text>
        <text y="278.405"
                x="328.269">(</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="333.057">0</text>
        <text y="278.405"
                x="339.714">)</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="348.487">−</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="362.152">1</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="368.809">2</text>
        <text y="308.353"
                x="243.006">|</text>
        <text y="308.353"
                x="246.597">0</text>
        <text y="308.353"
                x="256.24">−</text>
        <text y="308.353"
                x="268.91">1</text>
        <text y="308.353"
                x="275.567">2</text>
        <text y="308.353"
                x="282.225">|</text>
        <text y="308.353"
                x="299.037">=</text>
        <text y="308.353"
                x="325.277">0</text>
        <text y="308.353"
                x="348.477">−</text>
        <text y="308.353"
                x="362.156">1</text>
        <text y="308.353"
                x="368.813">2</text>
        <text y="338.49"
                x="246.334">|</text>
        <text y="338.49"
                x="252.911">−</text>
        <text y="338.49"
                x="265.58">1</text>
        <text y="338.49"
                x="272.238">2</text>
        <text y="338.49"
                x="278.895">|</text>
        <text y="338.49"
                x="299.043">=</text>
        <text y="338.49"
                x="317.106">−</text>
        <text y="338.49"
                x="326.789">1</text>
        <text y="338.49"
                x="333.447">2</text>
        <text y="368.627"
                x="257.756">1</text>
        <text y="368.627"
                x="264.414">2</text>
        <text y="368.627"
                x="299.033">=</text>
        <text y="368.627"
                x="317.095">−</text>
        <text y="368.627"
                x="326.779">1</text>
        <text y="368.627"
                x="333.437">2</text>
        <text y="271.792"
                x="408.846">|</text>
        <text y="277.921"
                x="408.846">|</text>
        <text y="284.05"
                x="408.846">|</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="412.437">8</text>
        <text y="278.398"
                x="421.336"></text>
        <text y="269.61"
                x="429.041">6</text>
        <text y="286.823"
                x="429.041">5</text>
        <text y="278.398"
                x="436.894"></text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="446.392">−</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="459.061">1</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="465.719">2</text>
        <text y="271.792"
                x="472.379">|</text>
        <text y="277.921"
                x="472.379">|</text>
        <text y="284.05"
                x="472.379">|</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="479.955">=</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="493.62">1</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="500.277">2</text>
        <text y="278.398"
                x="509.18"></text>
        <text y="269.61"
                x="516.885">6</text>
        <text y="286.823"
                x="516.885">5</text>
        <text y="278.398"
                x="524.738"></text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="535.233">−</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="548.898">1</text>
        <text y="278.217"
                x="555.555">2</text>
        <text y="310.077"
                x="416.476">|</text>
        <text y="316.186"
                x="416.476">|</text>
        <text y="322.294"
                x="416.476">|</text>
        <text y="316.481"
                x="420.067">9</text>
        <text y="307.874"
                x="427.92">3</text>
        <text y="325.088"
                x="427.92">5</text>
        <text y="316.481"
                x="438.762">−</text>
        <text y="316.481"
                x="451.431">1</text>
        <text y="316.481"
                x="458.089">2</text>
        <text y="310.077"
                x="464.749">|</text>
        <text y="316.186"
                x="464.749">|</text>
        <text y="322.294"
                x="464.749">|</text>
        <text y="316.481"
                x="479.955">=</text>
        <text y="316.481"
                x="501.246">1</text>
        <text y="316.481"
                x="507.903">4</text>
        <text y="307.874"
                x="515.765">2</text>
        <text y="325.088"
                x="515.765">5</text>
        <text y="316.481"
                x="535.233">−</text>
        <text y="316.481"
                x="548.898">1</text>
        <text y="316.481"
                x="555.555">2</text>
        <text y="343.36"
                x="426.122">|</text>
        <text y="349.469"
                x="426.122">|</text>
        <text y="355.578"
                x="426.122">|</text>
        <text y="349.764"
                x="429.713">−</text>
        <text y="349.764"
                x="439.397">2</text>
        <text y="341.158"
                x="447.25">2</text>
        <text y="358.371"
                x="447.25">5</text>
        <text y="343.36"
                x="455.103">|</text>
        <text y="349.469"
                x="455.103">|</text>
        <text y="355.578"
                x="455.103">|</text>
        <text y="349.764"
                x="479.955">=</text>
        <text y="349.764"
                x="504.581">2</text>
        <text y="341.158"
                x="512.436">2</text>
        <text y="358.371"
                x="512.436">5</text>
        <text y="383.048"
                x="434.555">2</text>
        <text y="374.441"
                x="442.408">2</text>
        <text y="391.655"
                x="442.408">5</text>
        <text y="383.048"
                x="479.955">=</text>
        <text y="383.048"
                x="504.581">2</text>
        <text y="374.441"
                x="512.436">2</text>
        <text y="391.655"
                x="512.436">5</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I need to understand why this issue appears specially on Firefox, I found some articles talking about a sub pixel rendering, but I'm not sure if this is the issue or not

Comment: presumably you just need to increase the viewBox height a little.

Comment: Thanks Robert, but you have a reason for that ?

Comment: Tiny differences in rendering between browsers. Note that Edge and Chrome are the same browser underneath and both derive from webkit i.e. Safari so the differences between those 3 are smaller.

Comment: it may be a change of the font family